# Passing a symbol as an argument to a function

Tags: elisp, variables, elisp-macros, arguments

I'm trying to understand why this doesn't work, and how to make it work:

```
(defvar test/var-1 nil)
(defvar test/var-2 nil)

(defun make-setter (var-to-set)
  (lambda (val-to-set)
    (setq var-to-set val-to-set)))

(defun do-the-thing ()
  (let ((the-val 5))
    (funcall (make-setter test/var-2) the-val)))

(do-the-thing) ;; After this function is called, I'd expect 
               ;; test/var-2 to have the value 5, but it's nil.
```

I *assume* the problem is that the call to `setq` is setting the value of the symbol `var-to-set`, overwriting the previous value of `test/var-2` with 5. How do I pass in the name of the variable to set and and set the value of that variable?

Comment: Your first problem is that `(make-setter test/var-2)` is passing the *value* of `test/var-2`, i.e., `nil`.

Comment: Also see [`(elisp) Setting Variables`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Variables.html)

Comment: What @npostavs said. `make-setter` should be a macro, if you expect `VAR-TO-SET` not to be evaluated before `make-setter` gets hold of it. You also have a problem in expecting a relationship between that local variable for the function and the other variable of the same name that is bound by the lambda form. There are really several things wrong with the code. You would do well to read some of the *Emacs Lisp Intro* manual, (*An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp*) available by doing `C-h i`.

Comment: @drew yes, I am reading it, thanks; I'm asking questions here because I find elisp complex and I haven't gotten my head around everything I've read. I appreciate the suggestion about macros, though. Will dig in to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, closures won't work in Emacs Lisp without setting `lexical-binding` to t for the file. Dynamic scoping (which is used by default) makes it impossible to create closures.

To turn on lexical scoping, put this as the first line of the file with your code:

```
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```

If you want to set the value of an arbitrary symbol, use `set` instead of `setq`, which quotes the name of the symbol you want to set.

When passing a symbol as an argument, make sure you quote it by putting an apostrophe in front of it.

Comment: This got me where I needed to get, thanks!